# How to Create Complex JSON out of Java libraries. GSON/JACKSON

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson, jax-rs

I am working on an API which needs JSON objects from instantiation of classes. I am looking into [GSON library][1] with java. And seems like it can serve me well as I need to have JSON based on classes(see below). An instance of those classes generate JSON output and should look like this:

```
 {
  "Command": "login",
  "uid": "123123123",
  "params": {
    "username": "dev_2454",
    "password": "4546845446"
  }
}
```

And the java classes are as follows.

```
public class LoginInfo {
    private String Command;
    private String uid;
    private Params params;
}

public class Params {
    private String username;
    private String password;
}
```

I am not sure how to begin. Any help is welcomed. Any other library example is also appreciated. Thanks.
[1]: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: Have you read this [userguide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) fully

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail?

Comment: I added the details. I hope it helps a little.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, try explaining the question a little further.
However using GSON, do the following with multiple files approach to create JSON. See the end for Jackson way of doing it.

Create `Params.java`:

```
    public class Params {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public Params(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Create `LoginInfo.java` :

```
public class LoginInfo {
    private String Command;
    private String uid;
    private Params params;

    public LoginInfo(Params userparams, String command, String uid) {
        this.params = userparams;
        Command = command;
        this.uid = uid;
    }
}
```

In your Main program import these two references.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
```

And use the code as follows to create JSON:

```
 import com.google.gson.Gson;
 .
 .
 .
Params params=new Params("dev_2454","4546845446");
LoginInfo loginInfo=new LoginInfo(params,"login","123123123");
Gson gson= new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String JSON= gson.toJson(loginInfo,loginInfo.getClass());
System.out.println(JSON);
```

Output will look like this:

```
{
  "Command": "login",
  "uid": "123123123",
  "params": {
    "username": "dev_2454",
    "password": "4546845446"
  }
}
```

The main reason to use multiple classes approach is to make sure that you can easily modify your code in future and help you develop robust GSON parser. You could also have empty constructors in the classes but need to have individual getter and setter for GSON to work properly to map the values.

If you have Jackson library however, you can use the following example.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
 .
 .
 .
Params params=new Params("dev_2454","4546845446");
LoginInfo loginInfo=new LoginInfo(params,"login","123123123");
String JSON= new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(argument);
System.out.println(JSON);
```

Goodluck.